# gSOAP specify Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: c++, json, web-services, jsonp, gsoap

I`ve developer webservice with gSOAP. One of methods returns json output. However browser requires passing headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin). Does gSOAP supports passing headers before sending data?

**UPD:**

Solution found. Just add some code to http_response function:

```
static int
http_response(struct soap *soap, int status, size_t count)
{
 /* some code goes here*/
if ((err = soap->fposthdr(soap, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")))
      return err;
  if ((err = soap->fposthdr(soap, "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, CONNECT")))
      return err;
  if ((err = soap->fposthdr(soap, "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type")))
      return err;
  if ((err = soap->fposthdr(soap, "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")))
      return err;
 /* some code goes here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never did find any way to do it in my own code - but I was able to do it by modifying stdsoap2.cpp which seems ok because you need to compile that into your code anyway.  What I did was add the ClientCertSubjectDN header just before the end of the http_post function:

```
/******************************************************************************/
#ifndef WITH_NOHTTP
#ifndef PALM_1
static int
http_post(struct soap *soap, const char *endpoint, const char *host, int port, const char *path, const char *action, size_t count)
{ register const char *s;
  register int err;
  ... the code of the function (except the return at the end) ...

  /* add more headers */
  if ((err = soap->fposthdr(soap, "ClientCertSubjectDN", "CN=IVR Production")))
    return err;

  return soap->fposthdr(soap, NULL, NULL);
}
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: I am using GET method. When I try to send headers in post manner they appear as part of returned document.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a somehow cumbersome way to add your own HTTP headers to your server's response without changing gsoap code.

1. Define a variable to store address of original callback hook fposthdr
2. Define your own implementation of fposthdr
3. Store address of function fposthdr in above mentioned variable
4. Set your own implementation of fposthdr
5. Within your own implementation of fposthdr use original implementation of fposthdr to emit HTTP headers

Code example:

```
...
/* Declaration of own implementation of fposthdr */
int my_fposthdr(struct soap *soap, const char *key, const char *val);
/* Definition of variable to store address of original fposthdr */
int (*org_fposthdr) (struct soap *soap, const char *key, const char *val) = NULL;
...
struct soap *soap
...
/* Store address of original function and set own implementation */
org_fposthdr = soap->fposthdr;
soap->fposthdr = my_fposthdr;
...
int my_fposthdr(struct soap *soap, const char *key, const char *val) {
    int res;
    if (key == NULL) {
        res = org_fposthdr (soap, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        ...
    }
    /* Make sure to finally call original fposthdr with key and value being NULL pointers. */
    return org_fposthdr (soap, key, val);
}
...
```

**Remark**:
Above example implementation of *my_fposthdr* emits the additional HTTP header after all "default" HTTP headers emitted by gsoap. The callback hook is called by gsoap once per header and once again at the end with *key* and *val* being NULL pointers. So you may let your code detect these NULL pointers and emit your own header(s). Finally you have to call original fposthdr with *key* and *val* being NULL pointers, otherwise no HTTP payload i.e. SOAP response will be sent.